# Correct english for Sleeping on an issue or Closed eyes for something

Tags: word-choice, phrasal-verbs

I want to say that media is (sleeping on),(have closed eyes on),(unconscious) about particular issue. How will i say that correctly.
Please share phrasal verbs and actual words that have same meaning. Thank you

Comment: The idiom is [to close one's eyes **to** something](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/close+eyes+to), not **on** something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the expression **"turn a blind eye to"** something - to make a conscious effort to not see something you know is wrong.

For example:

> Management often turn a blind eye to bullying in the workplace.
>
> The media has turned a blind eye to the Syrian refugee crisis.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/turn-a-blind-eye

If the media is genuinely not aware of the issue, then you could use the word **'unaware'**, or the expression **'in the dark'** to describe the situation.

> The media was unaware of the earthquake in Myanmar.
>
> Employees were still in the dark about the company's redundancy policy.

**In the dark** usually carries the connotation that the person was deliberately kept uninformed.

Comment: thank you so much, Is their any specific word for 'turn a blind eye'?

Comment: For 'turn a blind eye to', one could use 'overlook' or 'ignore', for example.

Comment: A related expression is to be **wilfully blind to something** - that is, not just to be ignorant of something or fail to pay attention to it, but to really make a point of ignoring it.